# How to make a window stick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some divs that are 100VH and I'm trying to make it where when I scroll just once it will lock on to the next div.  EXAMPLE: https://olaolu.dev/ (when you just touch the scroll wheel once it locks on to another part of the page)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView ?